# Algorithm and datastructure for calculating trig functions to arbitrary precisions

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

I need to do a lot of calculations to arbitrarily high precisions - in Javascript which only has a 64 bit float representation of numbers.

I can see how I could combine multiple variables to represent large numbers: for example to represent a large decimal of m digits, where the 64 bit floating point can represent n digits, I need m / n variables.

But how can I implement an algorithm that calculates tan() to an arbitrary precision, using only 64-bit floating point arithmetic?

Comment: JS floats are 64 bits, not 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to (re)do it yourself ? I'd use a lib for that. For instance http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html.